# What am I missing for components?

Tags: wine, java, 17.04, crash

So I have been trying to get a simple java based editor to work that was based for Windows. It is named "Final Fantasy V Advance Editor 1.0" and located [here](https://www.romhacking.net/utilities/907/).

Normally most other applications work. But this one does not. I installed Java separately for wine. So that was done. Now when I go to run the application. The task manager shows the .exe loading for a split second then crashes. I have gone through cmd and tried to run wine through that, I got this...

```
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x240000 0 0x23fcc0 4 stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x6d564650) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x6ea3b670) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x6f486ba0) stub
```

So it seems to suggest I needed to fix msvcrt, though i did not have it in my library. So I added it and ran again. No such luck came up the same problem. So i've ran out of options and thought I would ask the community on what I'm missing.

Comment: Which editor are you trying to install?

Comment: it does not need installing. It is an editor for snes roms so it can allow me to edit sprites and other aspects of games.

Comment: How it is named? Where we can download it to help you?

Comment: Answer both quests there N0rbert.
https://www.romhacking.net/utilities/907/

Answer (score 1):

You really do not need Wine. Follow these steps:

1. download your file *FinalFantasyVAdvanceEditor_v1-0.zip*
2. Unzip it with `unzip FinalFantasyVAdvanceEditor_v1-0.zip`
3. Install JRE with `sudo apt-get install default-jre`
4. Run it directly as `java -jar FFVAEditor.exe`